# Variable appearing above html in php when using return

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to put the variable `$about` inside of the html I am returning...however when I view the output, it puts `$about` above the html code...

```
function cc_shortcode( $atts ) {

 $other_page = 498;
 $about = the_field('cc_about_this_course', $other_page);

    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '',
    ), $atts) );
    $result = '<div class="main">
<div class="accordion">
<div class="accordion-section">

<a class="accordion-section-title active" href="#accordion-1">ABOUT THIS COURSE<i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></a>
<div id="accordion-1" class="accordion-section-content open" style="display: block;">
<p>' . $about . '</p>
</div>
</div>
';

    return $result;


}
```

Comment: does `$about` get outputted twice? does `the_field()` have any echo?

Comment: It does not. the_field() function just returns a variable of text. It does do an echo.

Comment: then i dont get it. `it puts $about above the html code` - what do you mean by this?

Comment: Just edited, it does do an echo, I just checked the documentation

Comment: if this is wordpress please tag it

Comment: It is, I did just find the solution in the documentation. But if someone could explain how echo effects this problem, I will accept it as the answer

Comment: you are calling the `the_field()` inside `$about`, if `the_field()` has `echo` in it, it will output text before you define `$result`

Comment: so use `get_field('text_field')` if you want to assign it to a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/

the_field used for displaying value from the current post that's why it display value..

solution to use get_field ; https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

if the there is not get_field.. (for common problems)... like this..

you can ob_start(); and ob_get_clean for you problem

```
function cc_shortcode( $atts ) {

     $other_page = 498;

ob_start();
the_field('cc_about_this_course', $other_page);
$about = ob_get_clean();


        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'id' => '',
        ), $atts) );
        $result = '<div class="main">
    <div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-section">

    <a class="accordion-section-title active" href="#accordion-1">ABOUT THIS COURSE<i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></a>
    <div id="accordion-1" class="accordion-section-content open" style="display: block;">
    <p>' . $about . '</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    ';

        return $result;


    }
```

Comment: @nogad yes bro.. the solution is for if there is no get_field() .. so this applies to problems like this.. if you think still it's silly please tell... I will remove the outbut buffering...

Comment: Get field solved it, I fixed it before you posted, I just didn't know the function existed. Thank you